# Django Rest Framework nested serializer gives attribute error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nested, django-serializer

I am trying to setup a nested serializer below I've posted the models and serializer.  why am I getting the below error ?

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `balance_sheet` on serializer `StockSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Stock` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Stock' object has no attribute 'balance_sheet'.
```

serializers.py

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    income_statement = IncomeStatementSerializer(many=True)
    balance_sheet = BalanceSheetSerializer(many=True)
    cashflows_statement = CashflowsStatementSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        temp_income_statement_data = validated_data.pop("income_statement")
        temp_balance_sheet_data = validated_data.pop("balance_sheet")
        temp_cashflows_statement_data = validated_data.pop("cashflows_statement")
        new_stock = Stock.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for i in temp_income_statement_data:
            IncomeStatement.objects.create(**i, ticker=new_stock)
        for x in temp_balance_sheet_data:
            BalanceSheet.objects.create(**x, ticker=new_stock)
        for y in temp_cashflows_statement_data:
            CashflowsStatement.objects.create(**y, ticker=new_stock)
        return new_stock
```

`IncomeStatementSerializer`, `BalanceSheetSerializer` and `CashflowsStatementSerializer` are all typical `ModelSerializer`'s

models.py

```
class Stock(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.ticker
        self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "stock"
        verbose_name_plural = "stocks"
        ordering = ["ticker"]
```

`IncomeStatement`, `BalanceSheet` and `CashflowsStatement` are all typical `models.Model` with a `ForeignKey` relationship to `Stock`

views.py

```
class StockList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"
```

Comment: What is the `related_name` for the `BalanceSheet` -> `Stock` foreign key?

Comment: the `related_name` is `balance_sheets`

Comment: You need to include the "s" in your serializer field name to match the related name

Comment: if you post the answer I will accept it